# Preselected Angular data does not show up in Select2 multiple select menu

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I have a project that uses Select2 (4.0.3) and Angular (1.4.9). One of the forms, which uses an Angular controller and two-way data binding, loads a contact model, which contains many sites, and a list of available sites from a server. This data is added into a `contact` object and to a `sites` array, respectively, which are properties of the controller. I have implemented a Select2 multiple select which allows the user to update the list of sites belonging to the contact.

```
<select 
    name="sites"
    class="form-control m-b js-example-basic-multiple site-select"
    multiple="multiple"
    data-placeholder="Select Sites"
    ng-model="contact.sites">
    <option 
        ng-repeat="site in sites" 
        ng-bind="site.name" 
        value="{{ site.id }}">
    </option>
</select>
```

The issue with this implementation is that it does not show the sites that already belong to the contact when the data is first loaded.

The select element is turned into a Select2 before the data is fetched from the server, with `$(".site-select").select2();`.

What is the best way to integrate Angular and Select2 together to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding ng-options directly to the select element and removing the explict option elements entirely:

```
<select 
    name="sites"
    class="form-control m-b js-example-basic-multiple site-select"
    multiple="multiple"
    data-placeholder="Select Sites"
    ng-model="contact.sites"
    ng-options="
        site as site.name 
        for site in sites 
        track by site.id
    ">
</select>
```